# How to import multiple excel files (workbooks) of different extensions in R?

Tags: r, excel, loops, import-from-excel

I am trying to import multiple excel files, based on their titles, in RStudio. However, I have to create the directory to these files and these files are of two different extensions, .xls and .xlsx. I am confused on how can I successfully import these files in the fastest way possible.

I have tired to create some 'for' and 'if' loops and failed miserably. I have given an example below. I just don't know how to go about this. Even providing some sort of error message, using 'try/trycatch/stop' would be helpful.

```
a = paste0("subtitle1","subtitle2", ".xls")
for (i in 1:length(var)){
    b = try(read_excel(paste0(getwd(),"/",a[i])))
    stop('error message')
}
```

OR

```
if (i = 1:length(var)){
    a = paste0("subtitle1","subtitle2", ".xls")
    b[i] = read_excel(paste0(getwd(),"/",a[i]))
} else {
    c = paste0("subtitle1","subtitle2", ".xlsx")
    d[i] = read_excel(paste0(getwd(),"/",c[i]))
}
```

Comment: I'mguessing you want: `a = paste0(c("subtitle1","subtitle2"), ".xls")` to start.

Comment: In addition to 42's advice, I would suggest you walk through your code slowly and think about what's happening on each line. If you use RStudio you can send each part to your R session to see what is happening. In your for-loop you increment to 1, import a file, and then immediately stop with an error message. Also think about why `i = 1:length(var)` doesn't make sense in an if-statement.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I actually found another way of importing the excel files. Yes,  I was very aware that i = 1:length(var) wouldn't work, I was just very desperate and frustrated to find a solution. I really appreciate your response though!! Thank you so much! :)